# How to add enumeration to a custom Sphinx/JupyterBook extension

Tags: python-sphinx, jupyterbook

I'm writing a simple extension for Sphinx/JupyterBook for a directive called `examplenum` that will add a new title starting with "Example", then will automatically add the correct section and example number to the end of the title. For instance, if it is the second `examplenum` in section 4.6, then the directive will insert the title "Example 4.6.2" into the document.

I'm *very* new to Sphinx directives. I was able to figure out how to add a title and increment the number of the example, but I can't figure out how to include the section number. Here's my run function:

```
    def run(self):
        env = self.env
        example_id = env.new_serialno('examplenum') + 1
        example_sect = nodes.section()
        example_sect['ids'] = "Example"
        label = "Example {number}".format(number = example_id)
        example_sect += nodes.title(text=label)
        return [example_sect]
```

Any help would be appreciated.